# Autocomplete textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to develop a autocomplete textbox customcontrol. Please any ideas or sample code. I need to fetch data from database to populate this control

Comment: How far have you got already? What approach have you taken? are you overriding an existing control; if so which one?

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to *develop* one, or do you need to *use* one? If using it is the imortant part perhaps [the AutoComplete sample at the asp.net Ajax site](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [autocomplete plugin for jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete), as I shy away from the AJAX toolkit in most cases. Easy to use remote sources - see the demos from the plugin page.

```
 $("#someTextBoxId").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "SomeWebService.asmx/GetNames",
            data: "{ 'part': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.SomeFieldFromYourJSON
                    }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AutoComplete control in the AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).